# Error using namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm having the following error with namespaces. I've searched and tried to implement all the solutions that I have found, but I could not solve it.

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Models\Site\User' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php-sem-medo/ORM/index.php on line 4

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";
    use App\Models\Site\User as User;
    $user = new User;
    dump($user -> all());
?>
```

Model.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Models{
        class Model extends \ActiveRecord\Model { };
    }
?>
```

User.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Models\Site{
        use App\Models\Model;
        class User extends Model {
            static $table_name = 'users';
        }
    }
?>
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "php-activerecord/php-activerecord": "^1.1"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4":{
            "App\\":"App"
        }
    }
}
```

config.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
    require_once 'connection.php';
?>
```

Directory Structure is

```
php-sem-medo -> ORM -> App -> Models-> Model.php
                 |-> APP -> Models -> Site -> User.php
                 |-> vendor -> composer
                 |-> vendor -> php-activerecord
                 |-> vendor -> autoload.php
                 |-> composer.json
                 |-> composer.lock
                 |-> config.php
                 |-> connection.php
                 |-> index.php
```

Comment: I'm sorry you are write, i've just added. follow it again.

php-sem-medo -> ORM -> App -> Models-> Model.php
                 |-> APP -> Models -> Site -> User.php
                 |-> vendor -> composer
                 |-> vendor -> php-activerecord
                 |-> vendor -> autoload.php
                 |-> composer.json
                 |-> composer.lock
                 |-> config.php
                 |-> connection.php
                 |-> index.php

Answer (score 0):

`require_once()` needs the full path to the file not only the file name.

Try to concat your plugin directory and the file name

Comment: I've added the full path and two files.
index.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';

and in the file config.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/connection.php';

The error persists.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Models\Site\User' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php-sem-medo/ORM/index.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, apparently there was nothing wrong with the code it self. I had to ran the following command in the directory of the project...

composer dump-autoload

After that the problem was solved and I could accessed the desired information.